# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object' when reading json object

Tags: angular, api, service

I'm getting an obj info like this:

```
{"github": "https://github.com/Hipo/university-domains-list", "example": "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=middle&country=Turkey", "author": {"name": "hipo", "website": "http://hipolabs.com"}}
```

**api.service.ts**, i have the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor (private http:HttpClient) { }

  getUni(){
      return this.http.get('http://universities.hipolabs.com/'); 
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts** looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'University API Info - http://universities.hipolabs.com/';
 
  uniData: any ; //= null;

  constructor(private api:ApiService) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getUni().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.uniData = data;
    }, err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  }
```

**app.component.html** I have the following:

```
  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let uni of uniData">
     {{uni.github}} 
     {{uni.example}} 
     {{uni.author.name}} 
     {{uni.author.website}} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

I get this error:

> ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables.

Pls help.  thanks

Comment: only if we get api response as `[]` array, we need to use ngFor, else we can just use `{{uniData.github}} 
     {{uniData.example}} 
     {{uniData.author.name}} 
     {{uniData.author.website}} ` without the ngFor!

Comment: thanks I got it working. but now I have another issue.

Comment: Naren, I have some more stuff to follow up where I am stuck, do you think you can help me ? pls. msg msg me on linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/naheed-virk/

thanks

Comment: I can explain it here:
I have a dropdown with country code and uni info. for all the countries.
when user pick a countryCode from the dropdown, I need to display University info related to that university.

It's databinding where I am having issues.

Comment: Hi, please raise another stack overflow question and share here, I will check it out, if you could give me a working jsfiddle with all the data and a working example with the issue I can fix it!